# How to call a model with one to many relationship in Laravel5

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have a model like this

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Invoice extends Model
{
    //
     protected $table = 'event_invoice';

     public function payments(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\paymentrecieved','invoiceid');
    }

    public function comments(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\comments','invoiceid');
    }
}
```

Now if I want to get the invoice with all the payments and comments, How should I write the call

I did like this

```
         $invoice = Invoice::where('Id','=',$id)->payments()->comments()->get();
```

Its throwing error

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::payments()
```

Thanks & regards

Comment: `Invoice::with(['payments', 'comments'])->where('Id', $id)->get()`

Comment: @BenSwinburne sure Let me try it , I use to do similarly in L4 :)

Comment: Please don't tag a question with multiple versions.

Comment: @BenSwinburne I am getting one error `Cannot redeclare class App\paymentrecieved` this line is in the Invoice Model

Comment: @BenSwinburne I found out the problem the comments model had paymentrecieved as the class name I fixed it thanks

Answer (score 1):

`Invoice::where(...)` returns you a builder (`Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder`). **What you'd want** is a model (`Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model`), and you can get that by chaining a `->get()` (or `first`, `paginate` etc.) method at the end like `Invoice::where(...)->get()`. Only with this model you can call for a relation.

```
Invoice::where('Id', $id)->first()->payments(); // <- This is a *query builder* for payments of that invoice
Invoice::where('Id', $id)->first()->payments; // <- This is the collection (array) of payments of that invoice
```

---

**By the way,** it's shorter and more readable to use `find($id)` instead of `where('Id', $id)->first()`.

Comment: I did this and it worked $invoice=Invoice::with(['payments', 'comments'])->where('Id', $id)->get(); I will chnage get() to find() though :P